# In NBG set theory, if I have a class with a bijection to a proper class, is that class necessarily a proper class?

Tags: set-theory

In other words, is a bijection with a proper class a sufficient condition for a class to be a proper class?

The question just arose as I was learning about ordinals and cardinals and the associated paradoxes (Cantor's, Burali-Forti) that come when one tries to do something like talk about the size of the collection of all cardinals.

It seems that the motivation for calling these collections proper classes is that because when treated like a set they entail paradoxes, but the paradoxes seem to be specific to the nature of the set. The paradoxes don't seem to arise from the fact that they are "too large" in some sense to be called a set. Thus the question arose as to whether being "large enough" is a sufficient condition for a collection to be a proper class. In other words, is being a proper class about size or something more than size?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67786/bijection-of-proper-classes

Comment: What does the axiom of replacement say about it?

Comment: Also - welcome to math.SE. This is a valid mathematical question, but on this site we also look for context. Can you write anything about the motivation or background of the question, or how you came upon it? Are there related results that you are also thinking of? Think of a question as a small blog post, rather than just a problem statement.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the welcome. Cool blog btw. I made some edits, hopefully they make the question suitable now.

Comment: You could make the same argument about natural numbers and their subsets. Here "set" would be "finite set" (or "bounded set") and "class" would be "infinite set" (or "unbounded set"). The proof that the set of primes is infinite goes through "its specific definition" (it is in fact the first diagonalization proof, if you want to think about it closely). But if you take an arbitrary infinite set, it doesn't mean that it would be in bijection with a finite set, just because you don't have a "clean definition which provides an easy proof of its infinitude".